# Captcha Solving (font: Arial, line over text, no noise)

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, captcha

I tried to solve this captcha with opencv on python.

[image: Captcha with 4kynr with lines on top]

**How ?**

> I realized this was only **arial bold**, then I tried to generate all
>   the letters (lowers, and digits only) and match them with
>   cv2.matchTemplate()
>
> I followed [this
>   tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/),
>   but the multiscale is not sooo useful (the letters are always the same
>   font-size).
>
> You might notice below that I also tried to erode/dilate to erase the
>   lines that are slightly thinner than the letters, but it doesn't help
>   much either.

Nevertheless, I get some false positive that (trying to find **n**) that have a very high correlation coefficient (> 0.8)

[image]

Or same type :

[image]

Do you have any idea how to find another approach to this very specific captcha-solving ?

Comment: I suggest that this activity is unethical. Attempting to subvert the CAPTCHA protection shows a lack of respect for the owner of the server, whether they are doing it to protect their bandwidth or their business

Comment: That's a really interesting point of view and I was expecting it. Did you consider that maybe one crawl from me, would save a thousand page visit from my colleagues everyday ?